In Wix tool installer can we compare last digit of version number( skip first 3 digit)? and also can we remove the first 3 digits
I'm seeking to exclude the first three digits of the version number and solely compare the fourth digit with the older version build. However, when attempting to remove the initial three digits, I encountered an error: 'The Product/@Version attribute's value, '1941...4203', is not a valid version. Legal version values should follow the format 'x.x.x.x' where each 'x' represents an integer from 0 to 65534.
I want to compare only last 4th digit of versions. how can i do it?

"I want to compare only last 4th digit of versions." - That doesn't sound any more reasonable than comparing only the last octet of an IPv4 address and drawing conclusions based on that. What problem are you really trying to solve here?

When creating an .msi build using the Wix toolset, versions typically follow a format consisting of four parts: major, minor, build, and revision. If you attempt to alter this format, you may encounter an error similar to: "The Product/@Version attribute's value, '1941', is not a valid version. Legal version values should follow the format 'x.x.x.x'." How can this be resolved?
Additionally, if you wish to compare old and new builds using only the last digit of the version number, you'll need to skip the first three digits. How can this specific comparison be achieved?
